# Spring Boot Jetty Auto Redirect HTTP (Port 80) requests to HTTPS (Port 8443)

Tags: spring-boot, embedded-jetty, http-redirect

I have the following code to configure Jetty server:

```
@Configuration
public class RedirectHttpToHttpsOnJetty2Config {

    @Bean
    public ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory webServerFactory() {
        JettyServletWebServerFactory factory = new JettyServletWebServerFactory();
            factory.addServerCustomizers(new JettyServerCustomizer() {

                @Override
                public void customize(Server server) {
                    ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
                    connector.setPort(80);
                    server.addConnector(connector);
                }
            });
        return factory;
    }
}
```

and

application.properties as

```
server.port=8443
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore
server.ssl.key-store-password=xyzxyzxyz
server.ssl.key-password=xyzxyzxyz
```

My applications works expectedly when I access localhost:8443 but localhost:80 is not reachable. gradlew bootRun mentions

...
*Jetty started on port(s) 8443 (ssl, http/1.1), 80 (http/1.1) with context path '/'*
...

but upon visiting http://localhost:80 I get the message

*This site can’t be reached... localhost refused to connect.*

I am looking for http://localhost:80 getting redirected to https://localhost:8443.

I had it working in Tomcat:

```
    @Bean
    public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer(){
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory(){
            @Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
                 securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
                 SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
                 collection.addPattern("/*");
                 securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
                 context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
             }
         };
         tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(redirectConnector());
         return tomcat;
     }

    private Connector redirectConnector(){
        Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
        connector.setScheme("http");
        connector.setPort(80);
        connector.setSecure(false);
        connector.setRedirectPort(8443);
        return connector;
    }
```

But unable to find an equivalent for Jetty. Any pointers much appreciated.

Comment: You are missing an `HttpConfiguration` on your `ServerConnector` that needs to exist to at least identify what is ports are (secure vs non-secure).

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the required `HttpConfiguration` on your port 80 `ServerConnector` to tell Jetty what your secure vs unsecured ports are.

The Jetty side `SecuredRedirectHandler` is how the redirect actually functions.

See: https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/cookbook/SecuredRedirectHandlerExample.java

### SecuredRedirectHandlerExample.java

```java
package org.eclipse.jetty.cookbook;

import java.net.URL;

import org.eclipse.jetty.cookbook.handlers.HelloHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.SecureRequestCustomizer;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.SecuredRedirectHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory;

public class SecuredRedirectHandlerExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Server server = new Server();
        int httpPort = 8080;
        int httpsPort = 8443;

        // Setup HTTP Connector
        HttpConfiguration httpConf = new HttpConfiguration();
        httpConf.setSecurePort(httpsPort);
        httpConf.setSecureScheme("https");

        // Establish the HTTP ServerConnector
        ServerConnector httpConnector = new ServerConnector(server,
                new HttpConnectionFactory(httpConf));
        httpConnector.setPort(httpPort);
        server.addConnector(httpConnector);

        // Find Keystore for SSL
        ClassLoader cl = SecuredRedirectHandlerExample.class.getClassLoader();
        String keystoreResource = "ssl/keystore";
        URL f = cl.getResource(keystoreResource);
        if (f == null)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to find " + keystoreResource);
        }

        // Setup SSL
        SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
        sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePath(f.toExternalForm());
        sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("OBF:1vny1zlo1x8e1vnw1vn61x8g1zlu1vn4");
        sslContextFactory.setKeyManagerPassword("OBF:1u2u1wml1z7s1z7a1wnl1u2g");

        // Setup HTTPS Configuration
        HttpConfiguration httpsConf = new HttpConfiguration(httpConf);
        httpsConf.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer()); // adds ssl info to request object

        // Establish the HTTPS ServerConnector
        ServerConnector httpsConnector = new ServerConnector(server,
                new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory,"http/1.1"),
                new HttpConnectionFactory(httpsConf));
        httpsConnector.setPort(httpsPort);

        server.addConnector(httpsConnector);

        // Add a Handlers for requests
        HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
        handlers.addHandler(new SecuredRedirectHandler()); // always first
        handlers.addHandler(new HelloHandler("Hello Secure World"));
        handlers.addHandler(new DefaultHandler()); // always last
        server.setHandler(handlers);

        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped. While the build goes through server.start() fails: "ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to start Server". If server.start() is commented, then there's another one: "BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate ...servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set".

Comment: Nice! The "always first" part for `SecuredRedirectHandler` helped :)

Answer (score 2):

The following configuration will set up a redirect from HTTP to HTTPS. It assumes that you already configure Spring Boot to listen on port 443 and SSL is configured properly.

```
@Bean
public ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory webServerFactory() {
    JettyServletWebServerFactory factory = new JettyServletWebServerFactory();
    factory.addServerCustomizers(new JettyServerCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public void customize(Server server) {
            final HttpConnectionFactory httpConnectionFactory = server.getConnectors()[0].getConnectionFactory(HttpConnectionFactory.class);

            final ServerConnector httpConnector = new ServerConnector(server, httpConnectionFactory);
            httpConnector.setPort(80 /* HTTP */);
            server.addConnector(httpConnector);

            final HandlerList handlerList = new HandlerList();
            handlerList.addHandler(new SecuredRedirectHandler());
            for(Handler handler : server.getHandlers())
                handlerList.addHandler(handler);
            server.setHandler(handlerList);
        }
    });
    return factory;
}
```